# Failed to download pear/HTTP_Request2 within preferred state "stable"

Tags: phpunit, pear, httprequest

When trying to do

```
pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
```

I get the following error

```
    Failed to download pear/HTTP_Request2 within preferred state "stable", latest release is version 2.0.0RC1, stability "beta", use "channel://pear.php.net/HTTP_Request2-2.0.0RC1" to install
phpunit/PHPUnit can optionally use PHP extension "curl"
phpunit/PHPUnit can optionally use PHP extension "dbus"
pear/XML_RPC2 requires package "pear/HTTP_Request2" (version >= 0.6.0)
phpunit/PHPUnit requires package "pear/XML_RPC2"
No valid packages found
install failed
```

It says right there to use another channel, but I can't seem to discover or add that channel! What's the correct command to do this, or what else could I do?

Thank you very much,
MrB

edit:

Got it, wow, 10s after posting.

```
pear install HTTP_Request2-2.0.0RC1
```

Comment: post your solution as an answer to your question and accept it. It helps other people to see that your problem is solved and when people search for the issue they spot the answer more easily :)

Comment: Thing is I can only answer my question after 24h or so.. so I never get around to do that :( Really annoying.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[As mentioned in the online PEAR manual](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/guide.users.commandline.installing.php), the PEAR installer by default only installs stable packages. If you wish to install a package that hasn't yet been declared stable, you can do so, without changing the preferred state, by also specifying the version number or its state when attempting to install it. Thus:

```
$ pear install -f package_name-1.2.3
```

Or, if a package is in beta you can install it with:

```
$ pear install -f package_name-beta
```

Similarly, if the package is in alpha:

```
$ pear install -f package_name-alpha
```

There is a 'devel' stability state too, but not that many packages are released in that state.
Sometimes the error message will include a useful hint, as seen in your question above ;)

Comment: This would not actually answer the question, the correct answer is the one @MrB updated.

Comment: Actually it does answer the question. It might not provide a solution that can be copy & pasted directly into a console (be it konsole, gnome-terminal or whatever), but considering the 'answer' is evident in the error message (i.e. do a $pear install -f channel://pear.php.net/HTTP_Request2-2.0.0RC1) and I've explained other ways of resolving the issue my response certainly could be considered an answer to the poster's question. Sure, it requires a little thought, but that's the point - and that's how people learn.